# Why does the whitespace that renders inbetween a sequence of inline divs not show in firebug's 'Style' inspect frame?

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

The first three divs (in green, yellow and red) in [this example](http://jsbin.com/urodit/39/edit) are `inline` and have a whitespace in between them. However, looking at `firebug`'s `Style` inspect and toggling on `Show User Agent Css` does not show any css that renders these whitespaces. Why?

Firebug version: 1.10.6

Firefox version: 16.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the whitespace comes from HTML, not CSS, in the form of newlines between your closing and opening tags.

The fact that your first three elements are displayed inline is what allows the whitespace between them in your HTML to flow along with them inline, as if the blocks themselves were part of the text. What the browser does is turn the newlines in your HTML into regular space characters when rendering it, so you see them all on a single line as a result.

Comment: This behavior surprises me because I thought every visual output was always fully translated from css. I thought unstyled html was only visible because the default css defined by the browser.

Comment: @Bentley4: The whitespace you see is actually part of the text (as I mention, it's newlines turned into normal space characters), so like any other text, a browser has to look at the HTML in order to know if it should render it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no parent element. Inline elements need a parent-block-element to stay in.

There are CSS-Properties like `text-space-collapse: discard;` but they don't work for your problem. To see your whitespaces i recommend the use of the Internet Explorer Developer tools. They are great, because they show you these layout-busters.

Comment: Do you mean that if you define a parent block element these newlines will dissapear? Because I tried [this](http://jsbin.com/urodit/43/edit) and that did not change anything.

Comment: There *is* a parent block element, and it is `body`.

Comment: I understood he meant a parent element *only* for those inline elements.

Comment: @BoltClock wrong. by reference (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/spec.html#body) Body allows only flow elements (block). phrasing elements ("inline") are not allowed. Body itself is neither.

Comment: @Bentley4: Oh. Welcome to the wonderful world of confusing terminology. Still, the rendering of the page doesn't have much to do with the markup itself. As far as CSS is concerned, `body` is a block element, and its box is the parent of each of the `div` boxes which you made to display inline, and so it behaves the same way in layout as any other block. That said I removed my downvote.